# Django radioselect custom renderer for jqueryui

Tags: django, jquery-ui

I would like to use jquery ui buttonset for a radioselect from a django form.  I am using the custom renderer below for the radioselect widget, but the input lands inside the label.  jquery ui doesn't work with that structure.  What do I need to change in the renderer to put the input tag before the label?

forms.py:

```
class SimpleRadioFieldRenderer(forms.widgets.RadioFieldRenderer):
    def render(self):
        """Outputs widget without <ul> or <li> tags."""
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s'
                % force_unicode(w) for w in self]))
class MyForm(Form):
    myradiofield = ChoiceField(
            widget=RadioSelect(renderer=SimpleRadioFieldRenderer),
            required=True,
            choices=(('a','one choice'), ('b','another choice')))
```

Here is how django renders this in the template:

```
<label for="id_myradiofield_0"><input type="radio" name="myradiofield" value="a" id="id_myradiofield_0"> one choice</label>
<label for="id_myradiofield_1"><input type="radio" name="myradiofield" value="b" id="id_myradiofield_0"> another choice</label>
```

Here is how jquery ui expects it to look:

```
<input type="radio" name="myradiofield" value="a" id="id_myradiofield_0"><label for="id_myradiofield_0"> one choice</label>
<input type="radio" name="myradiofield" value="b" id="id_myradiofield_0"> <label for="id_myradiofield_1">another choice</label>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `RadioInput` and `RadioFieldRenderer` classes for the issue and use `MyCustomRenderer`  as renderer

```
class MyRadioInput(RadioInput):
    def __unicode__(self):
        if 'id' in self.attrs:
            label_for = ' for="%s_%s"' % (self.attrs['id'], self.index)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        choice_label = conditional_escape(force_unicode(self.choice_label))
        return mark_safe(u'<label%s>%s</label>%s' % (label_for, choice_label, self.tag()))


class MyCustomRenderer( RadioFieldRenderer ):

    def __iter__(self):
        for i, choice in enumerate(self.choices):
            yield MyRadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, i)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        choice = self.choices[idx] # Let the IndexError propogate
        return MyRadioInput(self.name, self.value, self.attrs.copy(), choice, idx)
```

**If you want a solution client side instead:**

```
<script>
    $("label>input").each(function(index, item){                
        $(item).insertBefore($(item).parent())  
    })
</script>
```

**You can have the solution by modifying `django.forms.widgets.py`:**
scroll to `class RadioInput`

we will modify last line of

`def __unicode__(self):`

```
return mark_safe(u'<label%s>%s %s</label>' % (label_for, self.tag(), choice_label)) #OLD
```

goes to

```
return mark_safe(u'<label%s>%s</label>%s' % (label_for, choice_label, self.tag())) #NEW
```

Comment: Please, don't modify widgets.py, use object oriented programming (inheritance).

Comment: ended up subclassing both RadioInput and the renderer.  +1 for guetti.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
myradiofield = forms.ChoiceField(choices=YOURCHOICES,initial=0,
                     widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer),)
```

Comment: Where are you importing HorizontalRadioRenderer from?  It does not appear to be built into Django.

Comment: sorry, put the following in your `middleware.py` file `class HorizontalRadioRenderer(forms.RadioSelect.renderer):
    def render(self):
        return mark_safe(u'\n'.join([u'%s\n' % w for w in self]))` and then use `from middleware import HorizontalRadioRenderer` This will put all your group radio buttons on one line so that if you use jQueryUI groupRadio they will look nice

Comment: Sevenearths, have you used this successfully with jquery ui buttonsets?  It appears to be nearly identical to the renderer which I am using.

Comment: The radioselect in the linked code is what I am looking for, but does not appear to be rendered by Django.  Could you please share both your template syntax, and the rendered HTML from a browser?

Comment: The link is the HTML output (and template, because of the nature of radioGroupButtons it's predomantly hard coded) and the answer is what you need in forms.py. My advice is to play around with it and follow this - https://wikis.utexas.edu/display/~bm6432/Django-Modifying+RadioSelect+Widget+to+have+horizontal+buttons

Comment: Thanks for your time Sevenearths, but once again that code is identical to what I am already using and have posted in the question.